# How can I show Tasks in Outlook 2010's Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, tasks

I've been using the Outlook 2010 calendar for about 2 years now, but I haven't been able to figure out yet how to use the *Tasks* feature: **How can I have Outlook 2010 display my tasks in the calendar view, e.g. in the day cells of the month view?**

So far, I haven't used the *Tasks* feature and always stored tasks as calendar items, but it seems contradictory to me to be having a *Tasks* feature that I'm not using, and instead creating calendar items that I then categorize as something I called "Task" (and associated with an easily visible color).

Obviously, I'm missing something, but I couldn't find any information on where to find an option to display the tasks in the calendar.

Comment: The answer to your question, feature is available in 2013 and not in older versions. Please upgrade. Gmail already has this option.

Comment: @user288822: I see, thank you for the information. Unfortunately, I have no control over when my organization buys licenses for a new version, so I may have to wait for a while till i can use that feature.

Answer (score 9):

I was wondering the same thing and just found something that works. If you view your calender in "month view" and have the "To Do" bar showing. (Mine is on the right side) You can drag the "task" item and drop it onto the correct day on your calender. Then when you print your calender all your appointments and tasks will appear together.

Answer (score 9):

In Outlook 2010, try the following steps:

1. Navigate to your Calendar.
2. On the Ribbon, Click on `View`.
3. Look for the `Layout` Section.
4. Click on `Daily Task List`.
5. Click on `Normal`.

   [image: Daily Task List on the Ribbon]
6. Click on `Daily Task List` and for `Arrange by`, choose `Due Date`.

At the bottom of the Calendar, you should see a section with your tasks:
[image: Task List at bottom of the Calendar]

This should work nicely in either `Day`, `Work Week`, or `Week` views (in the `Arrange` Section in the Ribbon).  The screenshot above was taken in `Week` view.

**Note**: The Tasks do not display in the `Month` view.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting this question, because I have often wondered about this but had not taken time to investigate. Here is what I found so far.

It appears tasks are only visible at the bottom of the calendar when in the day and week views. As an alternative to that, you can also turn on the "To Do" bar in your inbox or calendar view which will list tasks to the right.

[image]

Here is more information about [viewing tasks](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-your-tasks-HA010354416.aspx).

Comment: So they cannot be displayed along with calendar items in e.g. month view? :-(

Answer (score 1):

There is a third party solution here: http://tasktocal.com/
It puts the tasks in the "cells" of you calendar and thus "occupy" a timeslot.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tasks that last more than a day, go to your week view. Drag the item into the area below the row of days at the top of the calendar. This will create a view in all calendars where you can see the task.
Alternatively, double click in that area and type the task details in. Do not forget to put in the start and finish dates.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what I am looking for. I can drag tasks onto the calendar irrespective of the current view, but what is happening then is *that a new event is created with some textual information about the task*. e.g. I can define a task that is due on Nov 30, and drag that onto Nov 28, thus creating an event that says "Due date: Nov 30". That seems pointless to me; neither is the due date of the task visible in the calendar automatically like that, nor are later changes in the task reflected in the event. Like that, I could just do away with the task and just create an event myself.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after reading all the comments from the users who posted a response to the question of "how do I get Tasks onto the Calendar for the day/week, etc. that it is specifically entered for..." Here is what I believe IMHO is the answer, and it isn't upgrading to Office 2013.

Go to the "View" Tab. Click on the "Change View" to drop down the Menu. Then click on the "Preview" Option and this will put all of your Tasks on your calendar for the specific day/week you have entered it for.